# flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create returns error 255

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

so I've been trying to figure this problem out for sometime now but to no avail.
I've been tryna utilise the **flutter_native_splash** package to build a splash screen for my project.
Whenever I run

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

> I get the pub finished with exit code 225.

This is the actual error message:
**Unhandled exception:
Exception: Your `pubspec.yaml` file does not contain a `flutter_native_splash` section.
#0      getConfig (package:flutter_native_splash/cli_commands.dart:360:5)
#1      createSplash (package:flutter_native_splash/cli_commands.dart:40:18)
#2      main (file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_splash-2.2.16/bin/create.dart:12:3)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
pub finished with exit code 255**

I tried to build a splash screen for my flutter project.
I did the necessary pubspec configuration by adding the flutter_native_splash line to the dependancies.

I Specified the colors for both dark and light themes.

Comment: Hello, you said by calling the command above, means that your native splash setup found in pubspec.ymal.

Please I did not quite understand that...

Answer (score 0):

by calling the command above, means that your native splash setup found in `pubspec.ymal` file.

- `pubspec.ymal`

```
name: app_name
description: lorem ipusm
  #...

dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.2
  #... another dependecies here

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# // add this line for setup
flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: your_assets.png
  image: your_image.png
  android_gravity: center
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
# ....
```

after that

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```